# Windows Batch: replace substring in CSV file

Tags: csv, batch-file, replace

This is a popular subject on the Web but I can't find a simple way to do a find-and-replace inside a CSV file. My CSV file looks like this:

```
"0.219530613504834,43.7737904197643,PR RUE D'ARTOIS"
"0.522235882011867,41.7681203998576,PR DE LA FOSSE AU ROI"
"0.039404145384227,44.7565229712732,PR DES PETITS PRES"
```

I need to remove double quotes at the beginning and end of each line.

I tried the following script:

```
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

for /f "tokens=*" %%a in (D:/data.csv) do (
    set temp=%%a
    set temp=%temp:^"=%
)
```

My logic is to store each line in `%%a` and to replace the double quotes by nothing.

I escape the double quote with ^.

This script is doing nothing. Could you help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your attempt has several issues:

1. You need to use delayed expansion (use `!` instead of `%`). Without delayed expansion, the variable gets expanded before the loop is entered.
2. It's more reliable to use `"delims="` than `"tokens=*"`. With `"tokens=*"` each line is still tokenized, and then all tokens are concatenated separated by a space. But the tokens may have originally been separated by a `;`. So if you had "one;two" in the input you'd get "one two" in the output.
3. You don't need to escape the `"`.
4. You need to print `temp`, not just modify it without using the new value.

   ```
   setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

   for /f "delims=" %%a in (D:/data.csv) do (
       set temp=%%a
       echo !temp:"=!
   )
   ```

Comment: Thanks! But my file still includes double quotes. In the cmd window, I can control that `temp` is echoed properly without double quotes, but the file isn't changed (double quotes are not removed from it).

Comment: This doesn't make in-place modifications to the file. It produces new output, leaving the input unchanged. You can pipe the output of your batch script using ` > newfile` and then check the contents of newfile and, if it's what you want, you can replace the old file.

Comment: Thanks, that's what I was thinking about. I just wanted to make sure that it was not possible to do directly inside the input.

Comment: You are correct that many people use `"tokens=*"` when they really should use `"delims="`. But your explanation is wrong - `tokens=*` does not tokenize the entire line. It simply strips leading delimiters from the line, and leaves the rest alone.

Answer (score 2):

There is a much simpler solution that avoids delayed expansion altogther - The `~` modifier strips enclosing quotes from FOR variable content.

```
for /f "delims=" %%a in (D:/data.csv) do echo %%~a
```

Comment: Good job! This do the job perfectly... However, I will prefer @Klitos Kyriacou's answer as I also have a few double quotes inside the lines that I need to get rid of too.

Comment: @wiltomap - Be careful about removing additional quotes from a CSV file - they may be important.

Comment: OK @dbenham, thanks for the warning! Anyway, my CSV file is very simple and I'm sure I can delete these characters safely.